# How to order a css file?

Tags: css

I have a css file having more than 3000 lines. (yeah it's a bit much) I want to order them in alphabetical order so that I can find properties easily. Ctrl+F tires me lot since I have so many similar selectors. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want us to do...? Start with A and finish with Z. But I think that it is not going to work for you because of inheritance, you are going to have some problems when you want it alphabetical. Start sorting the styles in groups to keep it clean.

Comment: There are dynamic CSS frameworks like LESS and SASS.  They make it easy to pull your css apart into different, maintainable files (and still be able to decide the order in which they are called).  You could do it by hand, but at this point it's probably going to be painful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was looking my questions I asked earlier I realized it doesn't answered. Therefore, I'm answering it now for other people.

Styleneat is perfect for organizing and sorting: http://www.styleneat.com/index.php

Answer (score 2):

The order in which your CSS is specified determines which properties take precedence over others.  I would instead organize your properties by a category system. For example group font props in one section, Background props in another, etc. this is one example, but different programmers have there own methodologies for CSS file organization.

Comment: exactly. also the css can be splitted up in seperate files which will be included in a specific order (page/layout-structure-css, elements-common-or-default-style, other-particular-styles, styles-loaded-depending-loaded-page, etc)

Comment: I took over a continuing project and thus don't know exactly which rules applies what. That's why I want to order simply by their name. I agree with you about CSS file organization.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to order css is to make groups for specific design and one group for the layout or often used classes.

I usually make 3 groups for layout :

- **Form** : styling inputs, submits, label, containers, ...
- **Typography** : colors, links, titles, paragraph, ...
- **Layout** : box sizing and styling

And then for each specific design, you create another group in your css file overiding old or creating new styles.